# How would I use Web Components with Haml?

Tags: ruby, html, haml

I recently learned Haml, which is a pretty cool language for HTML. It has revolutionized the way I write HTML code.

Now, I just finished reading [this article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-your-own-html-elements-with-web-components--cms-21524) and it got me thinking. Can I use Web Components in Haml similar to how I used it in Angular.js? Would it be possible for me to "include" Haml web components from separate Haml files, then call them with `%web-component` or something similar?

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's nothing in specific to do in HAML with the Web Components since it's an HTML feature, it runs on the client while haml is compiled to html completely before leaving the server side.

So, you can use WebComponents in haml the same way mentioned in the tutsplus tutorial (just translate each html code to the correspondent HAML one)

**Example:**

```
%head
  %link{ rel: 'import', href: '/components/my_component.html'}
%body
  %my_component{'sample-attr' => 'bla bla '}
```

Note: i'm assuming that you've created the directory `components` in the `public` folder containing your component `my_component`

Another Note: you should include a polyfill in some browsers if you want your web app to work on all browsers since currently not all browsers support this feature [read more](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/)

Comment: A bit late but this is still relevant to me. Thanks!